# Sqlalchemy: Undefined variable from import: metadata

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Am getting the above error when I declare the Base Variable in an external module. The Base Variable is declared in a the module db_connect.py as instructed in this post: [How to create ForeignKey relationship across two different files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262014/in-sqlalchemy-how-do-i-create-a-foreignkey-relationship-across-2-different-py)

In **db_connect.py** I have declared the follwing:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:pass@server:5432/mydb')
Base = declarative_base()
```

In **data_template.py** I have the following:

```
from db_connect import Engine, Base

class DataTemplate (Base):
    __tablename__ = 'data_template'
    id = Column(Integer(5), primary_key=True, autoincrement = True)
    version = Column(String(3), nullable = False)
    specification = Column(String(1), nullable = False)
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint("version", "specification"), )

Base.metadata.create_all()
```

**Question One:**

With the above, the tables are created which is good but I get the metadata in the **data_template.py: Base.metadata.create_all()** highlighted with the error: *Undefined variable from import: metadata* why does that error occur?

**Question Two:**

in **load_file.py** I have to import the DataTemplateFile Class from the **data_template.py** module. If I don't do this import, I get an error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'load_file.data_template_file_id' could not find table 'data_template_file' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'
```

However, when I import as below, it works and tables are created but I get a "warning" indication in Eclipse indicating that the DataTemplateFile import is unused. Yet if I don't import it the code fails as explained immediately above.

```
from data_template import DataTemplateFile

class LoadFile (Base):
    __tablename__ = "load_file"
    id = Column(Integer(10), primary_key = True)
    file_name = Column(String(250), nullable = False, unique = True)
    data_template_file_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('data_template_file.id'), nullable = False)
    loadfile = relationship("DataTemplateFile",backref=backref('LoadFile', order_by=id))
```

Comment: Are these warnings showing up only in Eclipse? Also, have you checked the database to make sure the Foreign Keys are being created?

Comment: @CarlosV yes, they appear only in Eclipse. Yes, the foreign keys are working. Is it that in Question One, eclipse cannot detect the imports I've done at the top of the file? But how can that be because the code still runs?

Comment: I'm *guessing* that Eclipse is doing some form of introspection and can't detect what kind of object `declarative_base()` returns? Sorry that I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

actually i had the same problem. and i solved it by going into the site-packages folder and bringing up the sqlalchemy folder a level.

so the path is:

> C:\Python\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy

that did the trick for me.

Joe

Answer (score 0):

You have to add flask.ext to the Forced Builtins

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had a similar problem in Eclipse. In 1 unit, I did:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
...
engine = create_engine(ENGINE_PATH_AUTH)
```

Subsequently I passed the variable "engine" to a method in another module

```
import sqlalchemy
...
class MyClass():
    ...
    def execute_query(self, sqlstr: str, engine) -> int:
        if not isinstance(engine, sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine): # causes undefined variable!
            raise ValueError("SqlAlchemy base engine expected, but %s found!" % type(engine))
        ...
```

However, when I wrote my code as follows, then the error stopped appearing:

```
from sqlalchemy import engine as sqlalcheng
...
class MyClass():
    ...
    def execute_query(self, sqlstr: str, engine) -> int:
        if not isinstance(engine, sqlalcheng.base.Engine):
            raise ValueError("SqlAlchemy base engine expected, but %s found!" % type(engine))
        ...
```